# Dingo API, use Database Query Builder

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder, dingo-api, lumen-5.2

Does anyone know how can I use the Eloquent Query Builder with Dingo API ?

Using Eloquent out of the box, it is working great :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection([ ... ]);

$capsule->setAsGlobal(); // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods
$capsule->bootEloquent(); // Setup the Eloquent ORM
```

And then in my model, I can use the Query Builder :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

Capsule::table('users')->where(...)->select(Capsule::raw('AVG(rating) AS avg_rating'))->first()->avg_rating;
```

I know that I can use Eloquent to get the same result, but it will only work with easy query :

```
User::where(..)->selectRaw(...)->first()->avg_rating;
```

Now with Dingo API, when I wanna use the Query Builder I've got this error message :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null
```

I guess that is related to the *setAsGlobal* method that I have never called in my *app/bootstrap.php* file. I only have this :

```
...
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

// $app->withFacades();

$app->withEloquent();
...
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code specific to your Dingo API. Does it `use` Illuminate\Database\QueryBuilder\ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was only about Facades.

Uncomment the line in *app/bootstrap.php* to use Facades :

```
$app->withFacades();
```

Now, I can use the Facade 'DB' and so the Query Builder...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is as I am using lumen that require illuminate/database : https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.2/composer.json

However, Dingo API in stable mode do not require illuminate/database. Could it be the reason ? Required packages are not automaticaly "sub" required ?